# usage of merchant_param1 in ccavenue form page

Tags: php, ccavenue

I would like to know the usage of merchant_param1, merchant_param2, and merchant_param3... merchant_param5 fields used in dataFrom.htm form file of ccavenue. I read in one of the posts that the value entered in merchant_param1 will echo back in merchant's webpage. Is it so? Will it echo automatically or should we get the value and print? Because I would like to retrieve order id back when it is redirected to merchant's web page from ccavenue payment page.

```
<td>Merchant Param1 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param1" value="additional Info."/></td>
```

Comment: the gateway returns the field untouched, you can use it for adding an id of something like that